# Where we can find full upgrading info

Tags: upgrade

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 (with all the LTS compatibility).

Almost each day we have more than one upgrading process of some internal component.

I want to know where in the web we can find all the details about this.

It is specially intended because today (May, 16, 2019) there was a `modemmanager` upgrade, and I want to know if it is related with an specific issue in my HP 250 G5 laptop internal WiFi modem.

Comment: It's unrelated.

Comment: Changelogs for each newly-uploaded package in the Ubuntu repositories are at http://changelogs.ubuntu.com

Comment: Oh, and Ubuntu Studio 18.04 is [definitely NOT an LTS release](https://ubuntustudio.org/2019/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-extended-support/). Your phrasing might indicate you knew that already, but just in case you didn't know.

Comment: I know that, thanks! But... to me, it IS a LTS (because its supporting time is longer than the typical 6-9 months).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use that product but a quick google led me here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes. I hope it's what you are looking for.